# GIMP: Gradient paintbrush

Tags: gimp, gradient, brush

Is there any way, in GIMP, to set the color of a paintbrush to be a gradient, the first color at the beginning of the stroke and the second color as the end of the stroke? I found [a help page from 2.2](https://docs.gimp.org/2.2/en/gimp-tool-painting.html) which implies that it was possible then, but the UI elements don't seem to have equivalents in 2.10 and 2.10 docs don't mention it. A layer with a gradient using the brush stroke as a mask does not do anything similar to what I'm trying to achieve.

Specific use case: I'm adding various climate layers to a (fictional) world map image. I'm trying to add wind lines in a way that makes it obvious which direction I drew the line. I will probably be drawing around 100 of these, so any solution needs to be do-once-use-often and cannot assume that the gradients will be in the same direction across instances.

Answer (score 2):

There is. For some inexplicable reason it is hidden inside the 'Dynamics' options, whose help page is [here](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-dynamics.html). One of the preset dynamics you can select is 'Color From Gradient', and it does exactly what the 2.2 dialog describes with a slightly different UI.

Comment: Not really "inexplicable". When things aren't constant how they change has to be detailed and this is done in "Dynamics". Changing with the position is only an option among others

Comment: AFAIK (but I haven't tried 2.10.22 yet), you can define a fixed length for the gradient, but there is nothing to auto-adjust the gradient painting to the length of the stroke, perhaps because pixels are painted once for all under the brush, and Gimp doesn't know in advance where the brush stroke will end.